# Android Spinner is Returning NullPointerException in Botttomsheet Dialog

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am trying to Return a spinner Value inside my BottomSheet Dialog.But It is returing NullPointerException always.Below is my String.XML File

```
 <string-array name="e_type">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</string-array>
```

This is my bottomsheet_activity.xml file

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/e_type" />
```

And I am trying to Get the value by below code

```
final BottomSheetDialog dialog3 = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_activity);

final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final String itemText = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

String requesttype=itemText; //Trying to use this variable but returning null

dialog3.show();
```

Why it is returning null , I have no idea

Comment: where is spinner? in activity file or in BottomSheetDialog?

Comment: BottomSheetDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinner is null because you are finding it from activity's xml file.
Try below code,

```
final BottomSheetDialog dialog3 = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
View mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_mine, null)
dialog3.setContentView(mDialogView);

final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final String itemText = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

String requesttype=itemText; //Trying to use this variable but returning null

dialog3.show();
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```
String requesttype;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final BottomSheetDialog dialog3 = new BottomSheetDialog(NewActivity.this);
    dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.lay_new);

    final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            requesttype=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.e("requesttype",requesttype);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    dialog3.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are picking up the reference from

```
final BottomSheetDialog dialog3 = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_activity);
```

so change this-:

```
final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final String itemText = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

to-:

```
final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
final String itemText = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```